# Regularly save Json data in my Firebase database

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron

I don't find on the web and Google doc how to retrieve automatically a Json data and save it in Firebase database.

**My goal :** every hour, call an external JSON  and save a data in my Firebase Realtime Database.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using Cloud Functions, which are snippets of your code that run on Google's servers. You can [run such functions on a schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), like in this example from the link:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

In that function, you can then run any process you want.

Cloud Functions for Firebase is limited to running Node.js code, but there are other solutions (such as [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler)) that can run many more languages.